# Resultado Busca PDO PHP Não retorna um campo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Faço uma consulta sql utilizando PDO PHP. Ao verificar o resultado da consulta, o valor de um campo retorna vazio, mas o campo tem valor. Utilizando a sentença SQL diretamente no phpMyAdmin o resultado retorna normal com todos os campos.

Nunca vi isso acontecer. Alguém pode esclarecer?

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Nome, IdTransacao FROM dados WHERE id = 1";
$busca = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$busca->execute();
$result = $busca->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

var_dump($result);
```

retorna apenas Id, Nome. IdTransacao tem valor mas não mostra nada.

Comment: Sem a consulta ou código é bem complicado inferir alguma coisa.

Comment: Chute no escuro. ???

Comment: @rray coloquei o código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de extrair (`fetchAll()`) os resultados da consulta é necessário aplicar (`execute()`) ela no banco de dados.

No seu código adicione essas linhas.

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Nome, IdTransacao FROM dados WHERE id = 1";
$busca = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if(!$busca->execute()){
    print_r($busca->errorInfo());
}

$result = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: esqueci de colocar mas tem o execute também

Comment: @lelopes acerta lá o código da pergunta. `echo $result[0]->id` vem em branco?

Comment: Não, os campos  Id, Nome retornam valores, o IdTransação não retorna valor, sendo que o mesmo possuiu valor na coluna.

Comment: @lelopes qual seria o valor de `IdTransacao` ?

Comment: valor do IdTransacao 10069930690006BE218A

Comment: @lelopes coloca o retorno do var_dump nos comentários.